# Bank payment transfer via stripe in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment

Hello there i want to transfer money from stripe account to customer account. Currently i am using this tecnique to transfer money to customer account. But i want to use the ach method for tranfer the money from stripe account to customer account so what should i do for that.
Currently i am using this method:

transection_controller.rb:

```
@pay = Stripe::Transfer.create(amount: @offer_transaction.amount.to_i, currency: 'usd', destination: @user.stripe_connect_account_id, description: 'Transfer for test@example.com')
```

I am new to rails and don't have that much idea. Any help should be thankful.